# GraphDB can not infer class of individual

Tags: owl, graphdb, reasoning

There is a class MotionPoint equivalent to (Protege syntax)

```
(geosparql:asWKT exactly 1 rdfs:Literal)
and (:hasSpeed exactly 1 rdfs:Literal)
and (:hasTimestamp exactly 1 rdfs:Literal)
and (:locatedInRoadElement exactly 1 otn:Road_Element)
```

And also there is a subclass OverspeedingMotionPoint equivalent to

```
:MotionPoint
 and (:overspeedingByValue exactly 1 rdfs:Literal)
```

So, having an individual X a owl:Thing with relations from the MotionPoint definition Protege Pellet reasoner infers that X is the MotionPoint.

Adding overspeedingByValue relation to X makes Pellet infers that X is the OverspeedingMotionPoint.

Finally, I imported this ontology into GraphDB, chose OWL2-RL rules set, but can not get a conclusion that X is the OverspeedingMotionPoint, it says X is only MotionPoint.

Please, help me to understand what I am doing wrong..

Comment: exact card. restrictions aren't part of OWL2 RL profile at all and for equivalent class axioms it's even more restricted to just value restrictions - so I doubt this will work. I'm even wondering why `(x rdf:type :Motion)` is inferred. Please check the OWL docs what can be done and can't: https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-profiles/#Class_Expressions_3

Comment: Yes, you are right to be suspicious about (X is a :MotionPoint). It is because of domain(:locatedInRoadElement) is :MotionPoint), sorry for that.

Comment: ok, yeah. Then my answer, OWL2 RL doesn't support your features. You can try `owl-max` instead, it supports more features

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you ask for is in OWL DL. GraphDB doesn't support DL, it supports RL and QL.

If (some of) your props are unique per class then you can easily infer types with RDFS reasoning, eg:

```
:MotionPoint a rdfs:Class;
  rdfs:subClassOf geo:Geometry.
:OverspeedingMotionPoint a rdfs:Class;
  rdfs:subClassOf :MotionPoint.

# geo:asWKT is subprop of geo:hasSerialization attached to geo:Geometry,
#  so is inherited by :MotionPoint
:hasSpeed a owl:DatatypeProperty;
  rdfs:domain :MotionPoint; rdfs:range xsd:decimal.
:overspeedingByValue a owl:DatatypeProperty;
  rdfs:domain :OverspeedingMotionPoint; rdfs:range xsd:decimal.
:hasTimestamp a owl:DatatypeProperty;
  rdfs:domain :MotionPoint; rdfs:range xsd:dateTimeStamp.
:locatedInRoadElement a owl:ObjectProperty;
  rdfs:domain :MotionPoint; rdfs:range :RoadElement.
```

And if all your props are attached to multiple classes: would it be too much trouble to assert the type when you record an instance?